# Continuity of an Analytic Function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity

I am trying to show that the analytic function, $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by

$    f(x) = \sum \limits_{n = 1}^\infty ne^{-nx} $

is continuous.

I don't have much experience with proofs of this kind, so I'm not sure if my solution (below) is completely rigorous, but I'd welcome any advice. Cheers.

**Current Approach**

Examine the series of functions defined as:

$f_N(x) = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^N ne^{-nx}$.

Note that the summand can be bounded by $\frac{1}{n^2}$ as follows.

Consider the sequence $a_n = \frac{3 ln(n)}{n}.$ Since $a_n \to 0$, we can always find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge N \implies |a_n| < x$ for any $x \in (0, \infty).$ For a fixed $x$, choose such an $N$. Thus,

$\begin{align*} \frac{3ln(n)}{n} &< x
\\ ln(n^3) &< nx
\\ n^3 &< e^nx
\\ ne^{-nx} &< \frac{1}{n^2}\end{align*}$

Let $\frac{1}{n^2} = M_n$. Since $\Sigma M_n$ converges, the Weierstrass M Test gives that $f_N$ converges uniformly.

For any n, $h(x) = ne^{-nx}$ is continuous (as the product of two continuos functions). Similarly, each $f_N$ is continuous (as the sum of $N$ continuous functions). Since the sequence of continuous functions $f_N$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$, $f(x)$ must itself be continuous.

Comment: If a power series is evaluated within its radius of convergence, it is not only continuous but differentiable there as well.  So do you see a way to consider $f(x)$ as a power series?

Comment: If $x=1/n$, then $ne^{-nx}=ne^{-1}$. The terms of the sum do not uniformly converge to $0$; so, the sum can't converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: $x$ cannot be defined in terms of $n$ since the latter is an index of summation (and the scope of $x$ is outside the summation).

Comment: @hardmath I'm not evaluating the sum at $x=1/n$, I'm evaluating the $n$'th term of the sum ($ne^{-nx}$) at $x=1/n$. One has the result: If the series $\sum g_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $I$, then the sequence $(g_n)$ converges uniformly to the zero function on $I$.

Comment: Try substituting $y = e^{-x}$ and follow hardmath's suggestion.

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-x})^2}$ certainly is continuous.

Comment: @ABlumenthal Interesting idea. After substituting, I'd be left with $\Sigma ny^n.$ Are you suggesting that I find the radius of convergence of this power series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the power series $g(y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n y^n$.  By standard techniques this has radius of convergence $r=1$.  Define $f(x) = g(e^{-x})$ for $x \in (0,\infty)$.  This composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Very clever! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ju'x has been cleverer in giving a closed form in the comment above.  That is, $g(y) = y(1-y)^{-2}$ and radius of convergence reaches to the nearest singularity.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to look at the interval $I = [a,\infty)$ for $a > 0$. On $I$, $|ne^{-nx}| \le ne^{-na}$, so the series converges uniformly on $I$ by Weierstrass. Hence $f$ is continuous on $I$, and by letting $a\to0$, it follows that $f$ is continuous on the whole of $\mathbb{R}_+$

Comment: Nice, in that you rehabilitate the OP's original approach.